# Как сделать Android приложение адаптивным под разные размеры экранов?

Tags: java, android, dpi

Как сделать Android приложение адаптивным, учитывая соотношение сторон (16:9, 3:4, 5:4 и т.д.), учитывая диагональ экрана и учитывая само разрешение. Короче сделать так, чтобы приложение выглядело абсолютно одинаковым на всех устройствах. В приложении используется ConstraintLayout, но его недостаточно, читал документацию, но там какая-то вода написана, в итоге пошёл методом "научного тыка" пробовать и сгорел.

Comment: А как выглядит абсолютная одинаковость на экране 5:4 и 16:9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании файла ресурсов в проекте,  Вы увидите такое окно:[image: Создание файла ресурсов Андроид]

Нажатие кнопки `>>` позволит Вам добавить условие по какому-то признаку устройства (на скриншоте для этого выбран параметр размера, `size`).

Соответственно, если Вы хотите создать по-настоящему адаптивную верстку, то создавайте файлы ресурсов под все возможные сочетания размеров экранов. И используйте эти ресурсы в верстке.

Ну, и не забудьте про изображения - если используете не векторный формат, то их тоже нужно делать много с разными размерами.

В целом, полностью адаптивная верстка - удел очень больших компаний, приложений с десятками миллионов пользователей. Так что советую выбрать 3-4 наиболее распространенных экрана и делать под них. На большинстве устройств все будет нормально.

Как дополнительное чтение по теме:

1. [Документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
2. [Урок из документации (на русском!)](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes?hl=ru)
3. [Статейка с рассуждениями на тему](https://www.whitesmith.co/blog/how-to-make-adaptive-android-apps/)

Comment: А я же могу в таком случае создать 2-3 гибких макета приложения и создать для них в папке "values" файлы "dimens", где я буду хранить сами размеры компонентов из макетов и менять их в зависимости от конфигурации девайса, или мне лучше создать квадриллион макетов для этих целей? :)

Comment: Макет обычно либо один, либо 2-3. Но внутри макета используются отступы из ресурсов, которые уже различаются на разных устройствах. Квадриллион макетов создавать - это, конечно, можно, но еще более больно